# Why am I getting a 'missing 1 required positional argument:' error?

Tags: python

I get the error message **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'environment' for the line  `player_o = QLearningAgent()`. Am not experienced in writing constructors. Please can you explain why I get this message and how I can correct it?

```
class RandomAgent:
    def choose_action(self, env):
        action = np.random.choice(np.array(env.available_actions))
        return action


class QLearningAgent:
    def __init__(self, environment, alpha=0.1, epsilon=0.2, gamma=1):
        self.environment = environment
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.Q = {}
        self.opponent_rewards = []  

        def choose_q_action()...

def play(env, player_o, player_x, episodes=1):
    rewards_per_episode = np.zeros(episodes)
    for episode in range(episodes):
        env.reset()
        # Let random player play first!
        x_action_index = player_x.choose_action(env)
        reward, game_over = env.act(x_action_index)
        while not game_over:
            o_action_index = player_o.choose_action(env)
            reward, game_over = env.act(o_action_index)
            if not game_over:
                x_action_index = player_x.choose_action(env)
                reward, game_over = env.act(x_action_index)
        rewards_per_episode[episode] = reward
    return rewards_per_episode


env = connect.Connect(verbose=False)

m = 10
n = 200
k = 30

# Test a random agent at episodes 0, n, 2n, ...., kn for m games.
np.random.seed(3)
rewards = np.zeros(k)

# player_o is the agent to test
# player_x should always be a random agent
player_o = QLearningAgent()
player_x = RandomAgent()

for kx in range(k):
    rewards_per_episode = play(env,
                               player_o=player_o,
                               player_x=player_x,
                               episodes=m)
    mean_reward = np.mean(rewards_per_episode)
    rewards[kx] = mean_reward

line1, = plt.plot(rewards)
plt.legend([line1], ["Random Agent"])
plt.show()
```

Comment: The argument contains `environment ` as a parameter with no default values. Hence this error is coming. You should either pass a value or set a default value to it.

Comment: Did you mean to write: `player_o = QLearningAgent(env)`? Additionally did you mean to write: `player_x = RandomAgent(env)`?

Comment: That is the framework code I have been given I am trying to write the rest to fit with that section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QLearningAgent`'s `__init__` method requires an `environment` argument which you're not passing.

Comment: I changed self.environment = environment to self.env = env, and I thought that the line env = connect.Connect(verbose=False), would pass the correct environment, however, this does not work still. Could you be more specific in what I should change?

Comment: Does `__init__` still require a positional argument?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: Then you need to pass that argument to the class constructor.  E.g., `player_o = QLearningAgent(env)`.

Comment: so in `def_init_` I need to write `player_o = QLearningAgent(env)`?

Comment: I added  `player_o = QLearningAgent(env)` to `def_init_` and I got this error   `[Previous line repeated 496 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. Do I still need `self.env = env`?

Comment: I’m sorry.  I misread your earlier comment.  You don’t want to call QLearningAgent within its own __init__ method.  What I meant was when you define player_o in your global scope, you need to pass in the environment variable.